# What's the number should be the "n" of new CyclicBarrier(n)?

Tags: java, multithreading, cyclicbarrier

Recently I learned CyclicBarrier, but here's a question:

Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static CyclicBarrier c;

    public static void main(String[] agrs){
        int threadsCount = 5;
        c = new CyclicBarrier(threadsCount + 1);
        // make 5 A threads to run
    }
}

public class A implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        // do something
       Main.c.await();
        // do something
    }
}
```

In about code, I wonder that why I must initialize CyclicBarrier by (threadsCount + 1) but not (threadsCount), since I never invoke await() in the main method?

Comment: You mustn't. If you run `threadsCount` threads, your code won't work because the number of Threads calling `await()` must be *equal* to the number of parties in the CyclicBarrier! You must be doing something wrong in the code you omitted. BTW: You did ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201274/why-use-cyclicbarrierthreads-1) yesterday, why was that deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` is the number of parties where [`new CyclicBarrier(n)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier%28int%29) creates a new CyclicBarrier that will trip when the given number of parties (threads) are waiting upon it, and does not perform a predefined action upon each barrier.

I would posit that the origin thread is counted as accessing the barrier, thus when you create 5 new threads, if you didn't wait on `5+1` threads then you'd trip before you were ready.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the exact number of parties that will wait on the `CyclicBarrier`, if you specify n+1, then you will have to have n+1 threads invoke wait on the `CyclicBarrier` in order for it to trip.